# Apply Bitbucket pull request as a patch

Tags: git, bitbucket, pull-request, git-patch

I've got a repo on Bitbucket that only I have write access to.

Someone forked that repo, made changes and issued a pull request to my repo from the fork.

How can I get that pull request as a git patch to apply temporarily to my repo for testing purposes?

The forked repo is private so I can't pull it down, and I wouldn't want to do that anyway.

On GitHub you can simply go to a pull request and add a .patch to the end of the url to download the patch. This doesn't work with Bitbucket.

Comment: Can you pull it into a branch other than master?

Comment: No. I could ask him to edit the PR to target a different branch, but I'd still have to accept it to be able to pull it.

Comment: Create a throwaway branch and ask him to edit the PR to that branch.  Merge it, and if you don't like it, just delete (`-D`) the branch.  Alternatively, explain to him that you're not going to merge code that you can't view, and ask him for read access to that branch.  (One of the things I don't like about BitBucket.)

Comment: Not exactly ideal, but I guess if I have no other options...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The Pull Request Patch is available through bitbucket API (despite there is no button to download it directly from the Pull Request page).

to access the Pull Request patch : https://bitbucket.org/api/2.0/repositories/GROUP/PROJECT/pullrequests/ID/diff

source:
https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-8323?focusedCommentId=2226612&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-2226612

Comment: Ha, this is my created issue. Still waiting on them to put in that link but I guess I should have answered my own question.

Comment: You can also create an actual patch (with commit metadata) by replacing `diff` with `patch` in the API URL

Comment: It says forbidden now :(

Comment: this solution seems no longer valid :(

Comment: Update Jira issue: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-8323

I can't believe 5 years later the status is "gathering interest"

Comment: Please adjust this answer, because it does not work.

Comment: Almost 6 now. Nobody built a plugin to export a diff as a patch?

Answer (score 8):

For 7.x versions you might try these links based on info from https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/7.11.1/bitbucket-rest.wadl and https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/7.11.1/bitbucket-git-rest.html:

Pull requests: `https://bitbucket.example.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/GROUP/repos/PROJECT/pull-requests/ID.patch`

Commits: `https://bitbucket.example.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/GROUP/repos/PROJECT/patch?until=COMMIT` (the `since=` query parameter can also be tried for a starting commit).

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Nick Spier's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22629641/3871020) above:

You need to include an access token with your request otherwise you will get a permission error.