# Bitbucket: solve conflicts on pull request on same branch

Tags: git, bitbucket

This is the situation:

- **John** creates a fantastic app and pushes the code to Bitbucket, we call this repo **aww**
- **Alan** checks out the **master** branch of **aww**, does some awesome changes, and creates a pull request from **master** to **master** of the **aww** repo

Alan becomes unavailable.

There are conflicts.

Please how does John fix the conflicts and merge the work of Alan?

Thank you.

---

OTHER INFO/EDIT

John tried very hard to checkout the pull request following [this post](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/a/33566860) but he is really not able to do it and from [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40948201/1815311) it appears to be impossible.

Comment: Use git log on Alan code and get the commit id and fetch it locally. than try merging and push the changes to master.

Comment: Thank Nishh but how can I do git log on a remote pull request? Is it possible?