# Fetch and checkout a pull request

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I have a private repository in BitBucket.

A team member has read access to this repository and has made a pull request to the main repository.

I want to be able to fetch this repo, so I can see the changes on my computer, without merging those changes yet.

After some time on Google I found:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/how-to-locally-fetch-and-checkout-a-pull-request-724402529.html

It says to hover over the new repo and the URL is shown below. However, the URL does not show on my browser. **UPDATE: Note that I do not have any permissions to access this repository directly!**

Therefore, my question is how can I fetch a repository from a pull request without merging it to my main repo.

Info in how to do this in SourceTree GUI will also be helpful.

**Update**

Note that `git ls-remote origin` gives output similar to the following:

```
$ git ls-remote origin
35xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx2d        HEAD
35xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx2d        refs/heads/master
36xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx        refs/tags/v1.0.0.0
bdxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx        refs/tags/v2.2.0.0
49xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx        refs/tags/v2.2.0.0^{}
```

Comment: can't you view the url by inspecting the element, if hover doesn't show it ?

Comment: Try to list all references at the repo using `git ls-remote origin`.

Comment: @phd done. see question

Comment: @dnit13 no it still doesn't. This might be because I don't have any permissions to access that repo directly.

Comment: Is the source repository for this PR the same as the destination repository, or did your co-worker fork the main repo and do his/her work there?

Comment: The employee forked the main repo, did the work there, and then made a pull request to the repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
git fetch origin refs/pull-requests/$PR_NO/from:$LOCAL_BRANCH
```

but there is an [open issue](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/5814/reify-pull-requests-by-making-them-a-ref) that states it's impossible to do what you want.

Found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/40948201/7976758. Recommendation there is to download patch for the PR and apply at manually.

Answer (score 1):

`git fetch origin pull/$PR_No/head:$Local_branch`

Then;

`git checkout $Local_branch` to view the remote Pull Request without merging.

Answer (score -1):

Once you can see that branch from your local (by adding a remote, probably) you can checkout that remote branch so you can see if the code is working fine and so on and decide to merge it or not. If you don't like it, then just go back to whatever branch you were on before.

```
git checkout some-remote/some-branch
```

Comment: I don't see the branch. How do I add a remote from a pull request?

Comment: But I'm wondering.... the pull request was against a repo that you aalready have as a remote, I assume, right? Then if should be there after fetching from your already set-up repo (the "main" one, say).

Comment: The only remotes I have is origin. However this is a pull request. And I can't seem to figure out where I can find this repo on my SourceTree or using Git